In react-router v6, how to "dispatch" different elements to different outlets or something functionally equivalent?
I would like (for instance) to have a 2-column layout where the route can determine which element goes into which column, instead of being able to only direct one element to one <Outlet />.
My dream would be to be able to do something like the following:
Layout.tsx:
const Layout = (
  <Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={2}>
      <Outlet name='side' />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
      <Outlet name='main' />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);

Router.tsx:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        element: {main: <Home />},
      },
      {
        path: 'address',
        element: {
          main: <ChooseAddress />
          side: <OrderSummary />
        },
      },
    ]
  },
]);

because I don't want to need to worry about the global layout at each step of my order funnel (all of them will display the same element on the side) and I wanna have the same layout for all pages, I want that side column to always be there - be it full of empty.
I know that I could do something based on a global context to emulate this functionality, or have my side column use the router context to determine which route I'm on and thus which element to show but that doesn't feel very clean to me.
How would you go about implementing something like that in a simple and robust way, if I made the desired behavior understandable enough?

the answer to the duplicate question is a bit off imho

You are free to explain where and why you disagree with the duplicate closure.

An alternative I'd suggest then would be to edit your Layout component to take main and side props and render these instead of Outlets since it doesn't appear you are actually nesting any routes. Does this make sense?

Does my answer here hit a little closer to what you are looking for? The difference being you want to specify what the "side" content is in the main layout route component. The basic gist is that you can have only one Outlet per layout route, so you just need to specify what the "other" content would/should be per route separately.
